# Array Split in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JavaScript  array as follows

```
let tasks =[
     {id:1,level:1},
     {id:1,level:2},
     {id:1,level:3},
     {id:2,level:1},
     {id:2,level:2},
     {id:3,level:1}]
```

I want to split this array into

```
let tasks =[
         [{id:1,level:1},
          {id:1,level:2},
          {id:1,level:3}],

         [{id:2,level:1},
          {id:2,level:2}],

         [{id:3,level:1}] ]
```

How to do this?

Comment: Would `[{id: 1, levels:[1,2,3]}],...` not make more sense?

Comment: Yes, can you suggest a way to do this?

Comment: Various solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using `reduce` helper, like this:

```js
const tasks =[
     {id:1,level:1},
     {id:1,level:2},
     {id:1,level:3},
     {id:2,level:1},
     {id:2,level:2},
     {id:3,level:1}];

const newTasks = tasks.reduce((acc, data)=> {
    const target = acc.find(subArr => subArr.find(item => item.id == data.id));
    target ? target.push(data) : acc.push([data]);
    return acc;
} , []);

console.log(newTasks)
```

Comment: Please try avoiding the anser for questions where the user have not done any valid attempts to achieve the result.

Comment: Although, a `_.groupBy` would be just as effective as that if using LoDash. Plus, the format suggested in my comment on the question would be more useful in terms of passing the data around

Answer (score -3):

You can write a loop to iterate through this array, push half to `a` and half to `b`.

```
a=[]; b=[];
for(int i=0;i<tasks.length;i++){
 if(i<=tasks.lenght/2){
    a.push(tasks[i]);
  }else{
    b.push(tasks[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't actually do what the OP is asking, you've just split the array in half.